# KNIME Column Combiner delimiter \t not working

Tags: knime

I use UCI Balloon dateset as example(https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/balloons/yellow-small.data)

1. load data and rename column names:

[image]

2. combine column "color" and "size" with a tab character. I use tab escape "\t". Now working:

[image]

[image]

Do you know how to input the correct tab delimiter here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think tab is possible in Column Combiner node. You can use [Column Expressions](https://kni.me/n/2_0ji_xeG-SudFu-) node with *join()* function. Example: `join(col1,"\t"col2)`. In output you'll see values concatenated but if you write data with CSV Writer for example you'll see there is tab. Why do you need/want tab between?

Comment: I just want to try different ways to combine columns. I found that tab, space as delimiter is not working for Column Combiner node. And I didn't find the answer in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Possibly give this a try:

Delimit *by* a space. Then replace that delimited with the tab \t.

Node Configuration:
[Image of node configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxKu5.png)

Resulting Output:
[Image of node output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVcIV.png)